# AttributeError: module 'lief' has no attribute 'logging'

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I have setup.py

```
import sys
import logging
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

# Replace 'metadata_gui.py' with the name of your Python script.
target_script = "metadata_gui.py"

# Dependencies (if any). Add other modules or packages as needed.
includes = []
excludes = []
packages = []

# Create the executable.
executables = [Executable(target_script, targetName="metadata")]

# Set up the build options.
build_options = {
    "includes": includes,
    "excludes": excludes,
    "packages": packages,
}

# Run setup.
setup(
    name="metadata",
    version="1.0",
    description="Your description here",
    options={"build_exe": build_options},
    executables=executables,
)
```

I tried

```
python setup.py build
```

and I have the following issue:

```
C:\Users\AM4\dicom\set_up>python setup.py build
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 3, in <module>
    from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .command.build_exe import BuildEXE as build_exe
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\command\build_exe.py", line 14, in <module>
    from ..freezer import Freezer
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 32, in <module>
    from .parser import ELFParser, Parser, PEParser
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\parser.py", line 29, in <module>
    lief.logging.set_level(lief.logging.LOGGING_LEVEL.ERROR)
AttributeError: module 'lief' has no attribute 'logging'
```

Appreciate all the help!

Comment: what version of lief do you have installed?

Comment: I have the version 0.12.3

Comment: If you named one of your own files `lief.py`, pick a different name.

Comment: and what is your cx-Freeze version?

Comment: cx-Freeze                          6.15.4

Comment: I have no file called lief.py